# moment.js change format based on difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I want to follow the same structure as content posting websites where new posts follow something like:

`(seconds/minutes/hours ago), (yesterday), (days ago), (MMM Do YY)`.

How would I rearrange the JS to follow this format and go to `(MMM Do YY)` after say, `3 days`?

```js
// iterates over every element with the .js-time-ago css class
$('.date').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    textDate = $this.data('date'), // gets the date from the date attribute
    postedDate = moment(textDate, ['DDMMMMY', 'MMMMDDY']).format(), // formats the date in a formate that will continue to be supported by Moment JS
    today = moment().format(), // gets today's date
    timeSince = moment(today, 'YYYY-MM-DD').diff(moment(postedDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'days'); // sets up the dates to be compared so that we can get a number for if statement below
  if (timeSince >= 0) $this.text(moment(postedDate).fromNow());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<div class="date" data-date="01 April 2018"></div>
<div class="date " data-date="26 May 2018"></div>
<div class="date" data-date="27 May 2018"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can acheive what you want by doing two things to your code first passing ing `'day'` into the `moment().diff()` function to get the difference in days then checking that value is smaller than 3 using a ternary statement very similar to an `if`.

I've cleaned up the code abit to show the 5 steps i'm taking

- Storing the time now outside the loop
- get the date from the attribute
- get the difference in days
- format the date based on if its less than 3 days
- appending that value to the element

```js
function formatDate() {
  const NOW = new Date();

  $('.date').each(function() {
    const DATE = new Date($(this).data('date'));
    const DIFF = moment(NOW).diff(DATE, 'day');
    const FORMAT = DIFF < 3 ?
      moment(DATE).fromNow() :
      moment(DATE).format('MMM Do YY');
    $(this).text(FORMAT);
  });
}

formatDate()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<div class="date" data-date="01 April 2018"></div>
<div class="date " data-date="26 May 2018"></div>
<div class="date" data-date="27 May 2018"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're actually really close - you just need to implement the conditional logic based on `timeSince` being within the range you want, in your example 3 days.

If you simply switch your `if` statement with a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (or even an IF-ELSE) that checks to see if the `timeSince` value is less than or equal to 3, you can achieve the desired result. Here's the ternary statement to use in place of your current `if` one:

```
(timeSince <= 3) ? $this.text(moment(postedDate).fromNow()) : $this.text(moment(postedDate).format('MMM Do YY'));
```

The ternary/conditional statement first takes a condition to evaluate - in your case, whether or not `timeSince` is less than or equal to 3 days ago. If the condition is true, the first expression is executed - in this case, formatting the value from your `.date` selector using Moment's `x ago` format. If the condition is false, meaning more than 3 days ago in this example, it uses Moment to format the text using the `MMM Do YY` format.

Complete CodePen example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zjgbmp

For an example of how a ternary helps keeps your code concise, here's the same solution using `IF-ELSE`:

```
  if (timeSince <= 3) {
    $this.text(moment(postedDate).fromNow());
  }
  else {
    $this.text(moment(postedDate).format('MMM Do YY'));
  }
```